# Rails field_error_proc - Change default error target

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I have the following desired html (slim template):

```
li
    label
        span
            | Password
            small.error ERROR MESSAGE
        br
        = f.password_field :password
```

**I wanna put the error (small.error) within the "span" above.**

My solution (so far) is:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
    if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
        %(#{html_tag}<small class="error">
        #{instance.error_message.join(',')}</small>).html_safe
    else
        %(#{html_tag}<small class="error">
        #{instance.error_message}</small>).html_safe
    end
end
```

But in this fashion the small tag has been placed right under the input tag.

Could I change that target location?

Comment: Similar question with answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341545/rails-actionviewbase-field-error-proc-moving-up-the-dom-tree/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve with javascript:

```
$("small.error").each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent("label").find("span"));
});
```